# Use Powershell to install English-UK language pack and set as default Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2022

I am currently trying to install the en-GB language pack using PowerShell however this is proving to be rather difficult.

The `Install-Language` cmdlet only works for client versions of windows (i.e. Windows 10).

I can run `Get-WinSystemLocale` which runs without issue, but running `Set-WinSystemLocale` does not seem to do anything.

Is there a way to download and install the en-GB language pack programmatically?

Comment: Indeed, the cmdlets in the [`LanguagePackageManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement) module are documented as being "supported on client operating system only." (I don't know why). Not having access to a server OS: Is the `Install-Language` cmdlet _present_ and actively refuses to run? Or is the module not present in server editions? If the latter, you could _try_ to copy the module over from a client-edition machine - no idea if it'll work. The system locale is separate from language packs and  the active UI language.

Comment: If you can find the source on where to download the individual language pack, probably the *Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center*, you should be able to add it using `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Source <path_to_CAB_file_directory> -LimitAccess -Name <LanguagePackName>`. Once the language pack is installed, you can set the system locale using the `Set-WinUILanguageOverride` and `Set-WinUserLanguageList` cmdlets. I've never tried it myself but maybe someone else can shed some light on if this may work